# How to insert byte array data with Linq?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, blob

I already create a table contain blob field and transfer the file into byte array.

But it will get error when execute the code blow to insert data into the table.

```
Table table = new Table();
table.FileName = FileName;
table.Content = Convert.FromBase64String(input_file);
db.Table.Add(table);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The error message is "ora-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested".

I tried to insert the same data by oracle executeNonQuery instead Linq and it would work.

But I wonder why it will get error when using Linq.

Here is the Table class content:

```
public class Table 
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the assembly I using:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.6

Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v3.19.0-beta2

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v2.19.80

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE" 
(    
 "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 "FILECONTENT" BLOB
)
```

Comment: You might want to include the definition of the `Table` class.

Comment: And the Oracle table DDL, and the version of EF and Oracle drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It would work after I add Column Type and MaxLength as below:

```
public class Table 
{
  public string FileName { get; set; }

  [Column("Content", TypeName = "BLOB")]
  [MaxLength(2147483647)]
  public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```